# YandexMap Получение координат выбранной точки на карте

Tags: ios, swift, yandex-maps-api, yandexmapkit

Использую Yandex карты в своем проекте, требуется получить координату точки на карте на которую кликнет пользователь.

Как такой функционал возможно реализовать с помощью mapKit?

Answer (score 1):

Yandex MapKit для iOS предоставляет протокол YMKMapInputListener, который позволяет получать данные о нажатиях пользователя на карту.
Больше можно узнать из его страницы на сайте [документации MapKit](https://yandex.com/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/3.x/concepts/ios/mapkit/ref/YMKMapInputListener-docpage/)